# jquery elements exclusion from an existing collection

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if there is a way in jQuery to exlucde a group of elements from a previously selected collection of items. I know I can use ":not" to add exclussion rules when referencing a group of items, but that is not the same question, since I want to know if it is possible to substract a group of elements from a different group of elements already referenced.

¿why is that? because imagine the first group is created according to a set of dynamic rules and some elements could have been added or removed, and when I want to substract the second set of elements from the first group, I dont really know which elements are in the first group. That is, there is no such rule that can be applied using selectors to obtain what I am looking for.

The idea is something like this:

```
var a = $("selection rules");
var b = $("selection rules2");
//elements from both groups could be removed or new ones added dinamically

var c = b.substract(a);
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to make more sense of your question (it's me and my brain that need a kickstart and has nothing to do with you), so would you be able to provide us with a little more code? Perhaps something very specific to your question and circumstances? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `not` method:

```
var c = b.not(a);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qfBuj/